# calling a serverside method in a javascript function?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Here i am calling a javascript function on a button click and i need to call the server side method inside the javascript function after finishing its execution.

**Javascript Function**

```
  function exportCharts(exportFormat) {

            initiateExport = true;
            for (var chartRef in FusionCharts.items) {
                if (FusionCharts.items[chartRef].exportChart) {
                    document.getElementById("linkToExportedFile").innerHTML = "Exporting...";
                    FusionCharts.items[chartRef].exportChart({ "exportFormat": exportFormat });
                }
                else {

                    document.getElementById("linkToExportedFile").innerHTML = "Please wait till the chart completes rendering...";
                }
            }

        }
```

**Server side Method**

```
 protected void imgBTNExportPPT_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               PredictExportToPPT objOExporttoPPT = new PredictExportToPPT();
               PredictionModel();
                string reportNames = ObjCommon.GetBIReportNames("Prediction", "Report");
                reportNames += ObjCommon.GetBIReportNames("Prediction", "Table");
               objOExporttoPPT.ExportToPPTPredict(ObjPredictInputParameter, reportNames, ObjSharedEntities.PredictTableData);
                string itemname = "PPTOutput.pptx";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "pptx";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + itemname + "");
       HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(DataTemplate.PPTOutputTemplateFilePath)));
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
               }
            catch (Exception exceptionMessage)
            {
                throw (exceptionMessage);
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

and i have tried like this

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#imgBTNExportPPT").click(function (e) {
            e.imgBTNExportPPT_Click();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "PEventPerformance.aspx/updateContent",
                data: "{}",
                success: function (result) {
               }
            });
        });
    });
```

Any suggestion??

Comment: imgBTNExportPPT_Click is the click even on the button #imgBTNExportPPT this should get fired when you click the button without you wirting JS? where your aspx code for imgBTNExportPPT?

Comment: You're specifying a `dataType` of `json`, but the code you're calling doesn't look like it returns JSON data; instead it looks like it serves up a file to be downloaded. If that is the case, you can simply do `window.location.href = 'PEventPerformance.aspx/updateContent';`

Comment: ya previously i used to call that one using onclick..forgot to change that one..now consider that one as a function and tell me how to call that one using ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `imgBTNExportPPT_Click` looks like an click event of a button. You may try the following to raise the event from JavaScript

Place this javascript in aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc() {
        <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(imgBTNExportPPT, String.Empty) %>;
    }
</script>
```

Call this function against OnClientClick

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="myfunc();" />
```

This will fire the server side event:

```
protected void imgBTNExportPPT_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: @nitinvertigo, I have updated the answer and I have also tested it, it is working now

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajaxpro for this purpose, If u want to generate a server side call without any event like button click.

In Your code behind file. Under the Page_Load section add

```
AjaxPro.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(YourCodebehindfilename));
```

In client side

call the server side method like

```
var content =  YourCodeBehind.Yourmethod(optional parameters).value;
```

In content you can get your response as an object and can do further changes

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to execute server side method is to use Web Services.

You have to write a Web Service that that contains your server side method.Then you can call it using AJAX.